# Screen unlock history

Tags: lock-screens, nexus-5

I have a Nexus 5 Android phone with standard pattern-locked screen. Is there a way to see a (recent) history of when my screen was unlocked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've not rebooted your Android, then you may be able to get the time stamp for the last few unlocks performed. Setup [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) in PC and execute:

```
adb shell dumpsys activity broadcasts
```

In the overwhelming (possibly) output,

- **For stock Android 6.0.1**:

  - locate the string *Historical broadcasts summary [background]*.  Following it would be the summary of some historical broadcasts.
  - In the new given info, locate the string *[android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT)*<sup><sup>1</sup></sup>. One of the next few lines to every matched line would show you the time stamp of a successful unlock.

    The order of matched lines would be chronological with most recent entry being the first to show up.
- **For stock Android 5.1.1**:

  - locate the string *Historical broadcasts [background]*.  Following it would be details of  some historical broadcasts.
  - In the new given info, locate the string *[android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT)*<sup><sup>1</sup></sup>. One of the next few lines to every matched line would show you the time stamp of a successful unlock.

    The order of matched lines would be chronological with most recent entry being the first to show up.

A demonstration performed on Android 6.0.1:

```
adb shell "dumpsys activity broadcasts | sed -ne '/Historical broadcasts summary \[background\]/,\$p' | grep -A2 'android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT'"
```

Output:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG]

In the output,

- enq: enqueueClockTime
- disp: dispatchedClockTime
- fin: finishedTime

  I do not know what they particularly correspond to but I can assure you that one of them is what you're after, possibly the first one. The output is in consonance with the rudimentary observation performed in parallel by keeping a tab on time during screen unlock.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup></sup> <sub>Courtesy of Chris for the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3451916).</sub>